# How to set toolbar in activity without the setContentView method

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

Im moving my app into material design but I got a problem on setting the toolbar in one of the activity because it has no layout.xml.

This is the activity.

GeneralActivity.java

```
package com.sample.app;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

// This class is for reusable purpose
// This class set some default configurations for all applications
// All activities in this Application except MainActivity extend this class
// so that the application can keep the same layout display
public class GeneralActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // enable icon for up navigation
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // set home button as back button
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

This is my **style.xml** for material design app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">

</style>

<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_green_600</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_pink_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/md_green_500_25</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/md_grey_300</item>

</style>

<style name="NavigationViewTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="textAppearanceListItem">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override setContetnView if you want to use that activity as the base activity

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I also try that but I got error here / enable icon for up navigation
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Sorry, I think i misunderstand your question, see my edited answer

Comment: @NikoYuwono I don't think it will work as question demands the toolbar in activity without layout. And your answer wants layout to be provided `setContentView` in order to get the toolbar in Activity.

Comment: @NikoYuwono I will try that later. Cause right now i have class. Thanks for answer

Comment: @VipulAsri read his comment in his code, this activity will act as a Base Activity where all activity except MainActivity will extend GeneralActivity.

Comment: @NikoYuwono I tried your solution but I got error in id.toolbar. Should I set a layout.xml for this so that i cab set toolbar widget? By the way this GeneralActivity.java will not be called in manifest

Comment: @ArozCaldo Hmmm, replace that with your toolbar id, no you don't need to set a layout xml for this activity, but you need to call setcontentview from the child Activity (The class that extend GeneralActivity)

Comment: @NikoYuwono Sir now I tried your solution and I got no error but unfortunately the app has stopped

Comment: @NikoYuwono there is no error sir. By the way im using AIDE IDE and i got this codes from github.com/itcuties/Android-SQLite-TODO-App-Example

Comment: @NikoYuwono the only problem here is about the action bar. Can I set different action bar for this activity? Like this <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> </style> , and how can I do it programmatically since this GeneralActivity will not be called in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

First for you activity without layout, you need oncreateview mathod for that to show something when this activity will be called.
One more thing, did your activity is mentioned in manifest.xml or not? if yes then it will by default get the action bar for the application tag mention there.
if not then you can declare particularly there.
try that out...

Comment: The activity is not mentioned in manifest. That activity acts as baseactivity for other activity. Example: Activity1 extends General Activity

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use the `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


}
```

Then you have to set different layouts for your Activities. You can use somenthing like:

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setMyLayout();
   }   

   protected abstract void setMyLayout();

 }
```

And in your Activity you can implement the method:

```
   @Override
   protected abstract void setMyLayout(){
        setContentView(myLayout);

        //... if you need to get your Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
   }
```

If your layout hasn't a Toolbar you have to change your Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mycolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. But sir is there any other way so that I will not change the styles.xml because I already established that style in the app. By the way this code sample Im experimenting came here https://github.com/itcuties/Android-SQLite-TODO-App-Example.

Comment: You don't have to change the style. You have only to use these attrs if you  want to add a toolbar without using a layout file.

Comment: Sir i already tried your solution but its not working. :( How about if I call a style for this activity especially this one: <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style> so that I can change the code from my action bar post to this: ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);.. Is it possible to set a different style for an activity?

Comment: But what if the GeneralActivity will not be called in Manifest so that it is possible to apply the theme or style, is it possible to do applying theme/style programmatically?